# Concurrent processing with partition based ordering in Reactor Kafka isn't working as expected

Tags: java, apache-kafka, reactive-programming, project-reactor, reactor-kafka

I am working on a sample reactive kafka application that will read from mulitple partitions(in my case 5 partitions) of a Kafka topic, concurrently process the records that must be ordered partition wise and subsequently publish the same to another topic. I took reference from [this link](https://projectreactor.io/docs/kafka/release/reference/#concurrent-ordered) to write the code.

Please refer the sample code below:

```
   @Bean
    Map<String, Object> kafkaConsumerConfiguration() {
        Map<String, Object> configuration = new HashMap<>();
        configuration.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        configuration.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "sampleGroupId");
        configuration.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        configuration.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        configuration.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        return configuration;
    }

    @Bean
    ReceiverOptions kafkaReceiverOptions(@Value("${kafka.topic.in}") String inTopicName) {
        ReceiverOptions<String, String> options = ReceiverOptions.create(kafkaConsumerConfiguration());
        return options.addAssignListener(assignments -> log.info("Assigned: " + assignments))
                .subscription(Collections.singletonList(inTopicName));
    }

    @Bean
    KafkaReceiver<String, String> reactiveKafkaReceiver(ReceiverOptions<String, String> kafkaReceiverOptions) {
        return KafkaReceiver.create(kafkaReceiverOptions);
    }


    @EventListener(ApplicationStartedEvent.class)
    public void onMessage() {
        reactiveKafkaReceiver
                .receive()
                .groupBy(m -> m.receiverOffset().topicPartition())
                .flatMap(partitionFlux ->
                        partitionFlux.publishOn(scheduler)
                                .map(r -> processRecord(partitionFlux.key(), r))
                                .sample(Duration.ofMillis(5000))
                                .concatMap(offset -> offset.commit()))
                .subscribe();
    }
```

On running the application, from the logs, I noticed that the scheduler created 5 threads one for each partition. Each thread is responsible to consume event from that partition.

The **problem** I am facing here is that all the 5 threads are not running conncurrently and hence unable to consume from all the partitons in parallel even though each of the partitions have 1000s of records to be processed.
This leads to significant increase in the total processing time.

Can anyone please help me with what am I missing here? Or how can we read from all the partitions in parallel and also take care of ordering within partition.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to create several consumers with `ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate`. At the same time, use a common `Scheduler` to execute business flows. In this case, each consumer will consume data independently.

Config:

```java
@Bean
@MessageFlowScheduler
public Scheduler messageFlowScheduler() {
    return Schedulers.newParallel("message-flow-scheduler", customKafkaProperties.getFlowSchedulerConcurrency());
}

@Bean
public List<ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate<String, RawMessage>> kafkaConsumerTemplates(@MessageFlowScheduler Scheduler messageFlowScheduler) {
    final var consumerConcurrency = customKafkaProperties.getReactiveConsumer().getConsumerConcurrency();
    LOG.info("Kafka consumer concurrency level is {}", consumerConcurrency);
    final var consumers = new ArrayList<ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate<String, RawMessage>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < consumerConcurrency; i++) {
        final var kafkaReceiverOptions = ReceiverOptions.<String, RawMessage>create(kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties())
                                             .schedulerSupplier(() -> messageFlowScheduler)
                                             .subscription(singleton(topicsProperties.getGlobalRawTopic()));
        consumers.add(new ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate<>(kafkaReceiverOptions));
    }
    return consumers;
}
```

Code

```java
@Service
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class KafkaMessageFlowListener {
    private final List<ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate<String, RawMessage>> consumers;

    @EventListener(ApplicationStartedEvent.class)
    public void startFlow() {
        consumers.forEach(consumer -> {
            consumer
                .receive()
                // ...
                .flatMap(receiverRecord -> receiverRecord.receiverOffset().commit())
                .subscribe();
        });
    }
}
```